# X-axis ticks will not update when zoom or pan

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph using matplotlib that will have dates - pulled from files - as a major tick and hours as minor ticks.  The code I have so far has this even though the text is all bunched up - I'm not concerned about that right now.  My issue is that if I were to zoom or pan, the ticks and their respective values do not update.  For instance, if I were to zoom into a single day, all of the days are still displayed on the x-axis.  I'm using Spyder as my IDE and Python 2.7.  Also, I should just throw this out:  I'm new to both Python and programming in general.

```
    hticks = []
    tickcnt = 0
    for i in range(len(MBTempvalue)):
    mcnt = mcnt + 1
    cnt = cnt + 1
    if mcnt == 60:
        mcnt = 0
        harray.append(str(hcnt))
        hcnt = hcnt + 1
        tickcnt = tickcnt + 1
        hticks.append(tickcnt)
        if hcnt == 24:
            hcnt = 0
    if cnt == 1375:
        cnt = 0
        days = days + 1
hours = days * 24
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
xmax = float(len(PS0AmbientTempvalue))
dx = hours/xmax
y = PS0AmbientTempvalue
y2 = PS1AmbientTempvalue
x = np.arange(0,hours, dx)
plt.xticks(darray,date)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(len(darray)))
minorLocator = AutoMinorLocator(23)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
minorformatter = FixedFormatter(harray)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(minorformatter)

l1, l2, l3, l4 = ax.plot(x,y, 'b', x, PS0AmbientTempavgline, 'r', x, y2, 'y', x, PS1AmbientTempavgline, 'g')
#plt.xlabel('Hours')
plt.ylabel('Temp - C')
plt.title('  PS0/T_AMB and PS1/T_AMB')
plt.axis([0, hours, (minscale1-5), (maxscale1+5)])
plt.grid(True)
fig.legend((l1,l2,l3,l4), ('PS0 Act', 'PS0 Avg', 'PS1 Act', 'PS1 Avg'), 'upper right')
plt.annotate(('PS0 Max = ' + PS0AmbientTempstrmax), (0,0), (0, -70), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va ='bottom')
plt.annotate(('PS0 Min = ' + PS0AmbientTempstrmin), (0,0), (0, -90), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va = 'bottom')
plt.annotate(('PS0 Avg = ' + PS0AmbientTempstravg), (0,0), (0, -110), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va ='bottom')
plt.annotate(('PS0 Stand Dev = ' + PS0AmbientTempstrstandev), (0,0), (0, -130), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va ='bottom')

plt.annotate(('PS 1Max = '+ PS1AmbientTempstrmax), (0,0), (8*hours, -70), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va = 'bottom')
plt.annotate(('PS1 Min = ' + PS1AmbientTempstrmin), (0,0), (8*hours, -90), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va = 'bottom')
plt.annotate(('PS1 Avg = ' + PS1AmbientTempstravg), (0,0), (8*hours, -110), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va = 'bottom')
plt.annotate(('PS1 Stand Dev = ' + PS1AmbientTempstrstandev), (0,0), (8*hours, -130), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords = 'offset points', va = 'bottom')
```

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that they do not update is that you are using a `FixedFormatter`, which are as the name suggests, fixed.  The main puprose for it is for putting text labels on ticks (such as making bar plots where the x-axis is qualitative not quantitative).  mpl is doing exactly what you told it to.

matplotlib can directly plot against `datetime` objects which is probably what you want to do here.

See [api](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) and [cookbook](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#fixing-common-date-annoyances).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

numdays = 5
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(0, numdays*24)]


data = np.random.rand(len(date_list))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(date_list, data)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Man!  That was a LOT of help!  I'm not familiar at all with the datetime method.  Is there a way to change it so that instead of a count down indefinitely it would count down to a certain date?  For instance, I will have a start date and a stop date.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm new, so I'm probably not using the best words to describe my situation.  Sorry.  The user will have a range of files that have the dates that data was inputted as part of the file name.  Based on the user's choice of that range determines the number of days that I want to plot through, and a lot of these files are 4 years old.  So I guess I'm saying that the dates will be user defined - they'll be variables.  Actually, what I have at the moment, is that range of the dates are in a list which I was going to have the first element be a start date, and the last element be the stop date.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much tcaswell for the help!  I couldn't have figured out my problem without your help!  Here is the code that I'm using:

```
def kuVpolFunc2(kuvdate, kuvit, kuviti, kuvfp, kuvfpi, faultflag):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime    
from datetime import timedelta   
kutempvalue = kuvit
kutempinter = kuviti
kufpvalue = kuvfp
kufpinter = kuvfpi
faultflagit = faultflag
date = kuvdate

datelist = []
#I first had to decontruct the filename pulled from the directory to put it in a format that Python could then create a datetime object.
for n in date:
    month = n[:3]    
    datenum = re.sub("[^0-9]","", n)
    day = str(datenum[:-4])
    year = str(datenum[2:])
    print ("Year:  " + year)
    print ("Month:  " + month)
    print ("Day:  " + day)
    alltogether = str(month + ' ' + day + ' ' + year)

    dateobject = datetime.datetime.strptime(alltogether, '%b %d %Y')
    datelist.append(dateobject)
start = min(datelist)
dlist = [start + timedelta(minutes = x) for x in range(0, len(datelist) *1440)]

#The 'add' variable is used to make sure that the dlist's dimension is the same as the           data.  It isn't posted here for brevity's sake, but I can post it if someone wants it.
add = max(dlist)



fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
l1, l2, = ax.plot(dlist, y, 'b', dlist, kutempavgline, 'r')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.title('Ku_Vpol Internal Temp')
plt.ylabel('Temp - C')
fig.legend((l1,l2), ('Internal Temp Actual Temp', 'Internal Temp Average Temp'), 'upper       right')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator())

plt.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.draw()   
plt.show()
```