# Set xlim for pandas/matplotlib where index is string

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that uses strings as index. How can I set xlim for the x axis when my dataframe index is of type object? I tried adding two additional years one at the end and one at the beginning where all datasets are np.nan but that didn't work.

Here is the dataframe

[image: Dataframe]

The datatype of index is object

```
df.index
Out[52]: Index(['2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'], dtype='object')
```

Here is the plot

[image: Matplotlib Plot]

So I would like to have some extra space on the x-axis in so the values for the fist and last year are better visible. What could I do?

**EDIT**:

Here is a minimal example using objects and not date objects as index

[ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/8103ae83ad79a23e7bfc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897864/avoid-points-on-edges-of-plots-when-the-last-x-value-equals-the-tick/16898296#16898296

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph

Comment: Also, to be clear, you are not plotting against strings, you are plotting against the position array.  `pandas` is just being (too) clever and re-labeling your tick markers.

Comment: @tcaswell the index is of type object. if it is a string or not is not relevant because I can't use set_xlim in this case. but margins looks great :) I tried this but seems like I did something wrong. Using ipython notebook not always updates the plot so maybe I should have just tried to redraw.

Comment: in either case, it is plotting your data against `np.arange(len(data))` so you can use `set_xlim`.

Comment: this is how it looks when using set_xlim on my ax object http://postimg.org/image/4rnex5u0z/d0936fee/. As you can see I have a the effect that I want but the labels at the bottom are screwed

Comment: ahh, right, because `pandas` is using as `FixedFormatter`, when you change the xlimit, it changes where the ticks are/how many of them there are, but the way `FixedFormatter` works is the first tick get the first string, the second the second, and so on.

Comment: The work-around is that a `FixedLocator` should also be used.  Are you using the most recent version of pandas? If so, I think this is a bug on their part.

Comment: Can you put up a minimal example to demonstrate this problem?

Comment: @tcaswell added a minimal example. Please see also my comment in the answer of CT Zhu. Using a locator removed all labels on the x-axis

Comment: It is far better to put the example code directly in the question, links rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': pd.Series([2,3,4], index=['2002', '2003', '2004'])})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(ax=ax)
```

which gets you the plot.  To take a look at how the x-ticks are getting dealt with look at:

```
# note this is an AutoLocator
print(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator())
# note this is a FixedFormatter
print(ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter())
# these are the ticks that are used
ff = ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter()
print(ff.seq)
```

This means that if you pan around the tick labels will stay the same, but will be at random positions.  This is the same problem as changing the xlim, the way `pandas` sets up the plot initially the tick labels are *completely decoupled* from the data.

One (verbose) way to fix this is:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(len(df))))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FixedFormatter(df.index))


# note this is a FixedLocator
print(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator())
# note this is a FixedFormatter
print(ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter())
```

This will work no matter what you set your index to (strings vs dates)

I have created an issue with pandas https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7612

Answer (score 5):

Use `set_xlim`, `+1` means moving 1 unit to the right and `-1` means the reverse. In the following example I expanded the plot 0.5 months each side:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(1, 11), 'C': range(2,12)})
df.index=pd.date_range('2001/01/01', periods=10, freq='M')
ax=df.plot(kind='line')
ax.set_xlim(np.array([-0.5, 0.5])+ax.get_xlim())
```

[image]

Edit, to have `xticklabel` for every year, instead the default every two years in `pandas`:

```
ax=df.plot(kind='line', xticks=df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y')))
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably another case where `margins` would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact it is likely a better idea to use real date objects and not "strings" as I did. Because with my index your solution does not work. Of course yours is the better solution. I will play with margins first

Comment: @ChristianRapp No, making your index `Date` objects is probably a better solution

Comment: If I use dates as Index how can I set which ticks are shown on the x axis? Now the plot shows only every second year as label but I would like to have each year displayed.

Comment: @ChristianRapp, `pandas` automatically does a lot of things, here it determines that having labels for every year is too busy and goes for every two years label. See edit for a work-around. It does means more work, but use `Dateindex` for `time series` data is often a good idea in `pandas`.

Comment: @tcaswell, in version `1.3.1`, `ax.margins(x=0.1, y=0.1)` raise a `ValueError: more than two arguments were supplied`. Shouldn't the source code be `if len(args) == 2:` and `elif len(args) == 3:` in lines 1835 and 1837 respectively?

Comment: @CTZhu This has already been fixed on master (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1787)  In 1.3.1 just call it as `ax.margin(.1, .1)`

Comment: and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412292/x-axis-ticks-will-not-update-when-zoom-or-pan/24416670#24416670 for a brief introduction to how to control date tickers.

Comment: @tcaswell, don't known that is already fixed. Actually the `locator` method doesn't currently work for `pandas` consistently, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337753/skip-gcf-autofmt-xdate-at-pandas-plot-creation/24337921#24337921

Comment: The 'this' I meant was the arguments on `margins`.

Comment: @CTZhu I don't have the bandwidth to chase down datetime issues tonight, if you think there is still a bug in mpl please make an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks for the locator hint. I tried to do this, but now all labels at x-axis are gone. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/a56b841316d92cffcd78

Comment: @CTZhu ah great, I just realized you edited your answer :) The trick setting the labels manually works. Nice, thank you! Still why does my locator not produce any labels? Crazy, I am having most of the problems with axes labeling